# WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant DeliveryMethods when moving code to ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, sidekiq, onesignal, rails-activejob

I have code to send invites to members of my website and it can be sent via email, real-time notification or One Signal. The code works great in development until I move the invite to an ActiveJob to be processed in the background using Sidekiq and Redis. I am doing this only for when a maintainer of an organization uploads a CSV file of contacts to invite to their organization. (Thus the background job as some clients wish to invite around 10,000+ people which would bog the system if done within the controller.)

If I move the task to an ActiveJob, I get this error in the Sidekiq output:

```
WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant DeliveryMethods
```

I thought that this was because I didn't put a `require` statement in the ActiveJob, so I added this to the top of the ActiveJob:

```
require 'application_notification'
```

But, I get the same error message.

I am at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here are code snippets. Please let me know if you need anything else.

**Versions**

Ruby:'3.0.2'

Rails: 7.0.0.alpha
`gem 'rails', :github => 'rails/rails', :branch => 'main'`

Redis: '~> 4.1.3'

Sidekiq: '6.0.7'

**Result Output**

```
# Terminal Output

Started POST "/import_wizard/organization/1" for ::1 at 2021-08-10 16:47:30 -0700
Processing by InvitationsController#invite_imports as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"--REDACTED--", "invitable_type"=>"organization", "invitable_id"=>"1"}
  Member Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "members"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/cookies_concern.rb:171:in `load_cookies'
  Organization Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:216:in `set_invitable'
  ImportResult Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "import_results".* FROM "import_results" WHERE "import_results"."invitable_id" = $1 AND "import_results"."status" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["invitable_id", 1], ["status", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:261:in `set_imports_to_invite'
  ImportRecord Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "import_records".* FROM "import_records" WHERE "import_records"."import_result_id" = $1 AND "import_records"."status" = $2  [["import_result_id", 32], ["status", "ready"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:155:in `invite_imports'
[ActiveJob] Enqueued InviteImportedMembersJob (Job ID: 69355585-cfef-4f1f-bf90-eae0f24d5f98) to Sidekiq(imports) with arguments: 
  #<GlobalID:0x00007fbeba81d0a0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://prayer-nook/Organization/1>>,             
        [#<GlobalID:0x00007fbeba81c6a0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://prayer-nook/ImportRecord/309>>, 
        #<GlobalID:0x00007fbeba817d08 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://prayer-nook/ImportRecord/310>>, 
        #<GlobalID:0x00007fbeba817470 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://prayer-nook/ImportRecord/311>>, 
        #<GlobalID:0x00007fbeba816d68 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://prayer-nook/ImportRecord/312>>, 
        #<GlobalID:0x00007fbeba816250 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://prayer-nook/ImportRecord/313>>, 
        #<GlobalID:0x00007fbeba8157b0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://prayer-nook/ImportRecord/318>>, 
        #<GlobalID:0x00007fbeba814a40 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://prayer-nook/ImportRecord/319>>],
   #<GlobalID:0x00007fbeb9a5f198 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://prayer-nook/Member/1>>
  Rendering invitations/invite_imports.js.erb
  Rendered invitations/invite_imports.js.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 10)
Completed 200 OK in 317ms (Views: 3.4ms | ActiveRecord: 95.8ms | Allocations: 57969)
```

**Controller Action**

The commented out line for `invite_imports_task` is a method I made within the controller with the exact same code that runs in the ActiveJob, but works. So, I know that the code works, its just moving to an ActiveJob that is now causing the issue.

```
# InvitationsController#invite_imports
# app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb

  def invite_imports
    set_invitable
    set_imports_to_invite
    @import_step = 4

    imports_to_invite_array = []
    @imports_to_invite.each do |record|
      imports_to_invite_array << record
    end

    InviteImportedMembersJob.perform_later(@invitable, imports_to_invite_array, @authenticated_member)

    # invite_imports_task(@invitable, imports_to_invite_array, @authenticated_member)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**Active Job**

```
# app/jobs/invite_imported_members_job.rb

class InviteImportedMembersJob < ApplicationJob
  require 'application_notification'
  queue_as :imports

  def perform(invitable, imports_to_invite, sender)
    set_import_result(invitable)

    imported_emails = imports_to_invite.map {|member| member[:email]}
    member_list = Member.where(email: imported_emails)
    member_email_list = member_list.pluck(:email)
    non_member_email_list = imported_emails - member_email_list
    sent_invites = []
    error_in_sending_invites = []

    member_list.each do |member|
      invitation = Invitation.new(invitable: invitable, sender: sender, recipient:member)
      if invitation.save
        invitable.invited_members << member
        sent_invites << member.email
      else 
        error_in_sending_invites << member.email
      end
    end
    
    non_member_email_list.each do |member|
      InvitationMailer.with(recipient_email: member, sender: sender).app_invitation.deliver_later
      waitlist = InvitationWaitlist.create(email: member, invitable: invitable, sender: sender)

      # in this case the member variable is only an email address
      if waitlist.save
        sent_invites << member
      else
        error_in_sending_invites << member
      end
    end
      
    update_import_records(invitable, sent_invites, error_in_sending_invites)
    update_import_result
    create_cue_notification(invitable)
  end

  private
    def set_import_result(invitable)
      @import_result = ImportResult.find_by(invitable:invitable, status: 'waiting')
    end

    def update_import_records(invitable, sent_invites, error_in_sending_invites)
      if sent_invites.count > 0
        ImportRecord.where(import_result_id:@import_result.id, email: sent_invites).update_all(status:'sent')
      end

      if error_in_sending_invites.count > 0
        ImportRecord.where(import_result_id:@import_result.id, email: error_in_sending_invites).update_all(status:'error_in_sending')
      end
    end

    def update_import_result
      @import_result.completed!
    end

    def create_cue_notification(invitable)
      hide_old_cues(invitable)
      CueService.new(@import_result, set_cue_recipients(invitable), false).call!
    end

    def hide_old_cues(invitable)
      Cue.where(cueable: @import_result).update(status:'hidden')
    end

    def set_cue_recipients(invitable)
      if invitable.is_a?(Organization)
          return invitable.maintainers
      elsif invitable.is_a?(Group)
          return invitable.owner
      else
          return nil
      end
    end
end
```

**Application Notification**

```
# app/notifications/application_notification.rb

class ApplicationNotification < Noticed::Base
  deliver_by :database, format: :format_for_database
  deliver_by :action_cable, channel: 'NotificationsChannel', format: :format_for_action_cable
  deliver_by :one_signal, class: "DeliveryMethods::OneSignal", format: :format_for_one_signal

  def format_for_database
    {
      type: self.class.name,
      params: params
    }
  end
end
```

**DeliveryMethod::OneSignal**

```
# app/notifications/delivery_methods/one_signal.rb

class DeliveryMethods::OneSignal < Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Base
  def deliver
    return unless app_id.present? && one_signal_url.present? && player_id.present?

    params = {"app_id" => app_id, 
      "contents" => {"en" => message},
      "headings" => {"en" => "Prayer Nook"},
      "include_player_ids" => [player_id],
      "data" => data
    }

    uri = URI.parse(one_signal_url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path,'Content-Type'  => 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
    request.body = params.as_json.to_json
    response = http.request(request) 
    puts "OneSignal response: #{response.body}"
  end

  private

  def app_id
    ENV['ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID']
  end

  def one_signal_url
    ENV['ONE_SIGNAL_API_URL']
  end

  def player_id
    recipient.site_profile.one_signal_id
  end

  def message
    if (method = options[:format])
      notification.send(method)[:message]
    else
      "Message from Prayer Nook"
    end
  end

  def data
    if (method = options[:format])
      notification.send(method)[:data]
    else
      { }
    end
  end
end
```

**From the Invitation Model**

```
## app/models/invitation.rb

def send_notifications
    if self.invitable_type == 'Group'
      GroupInvitationNotification.with(invitation: self, group: self.invitable, sender: self.sender).deliver_later(self.recipient)
    elsif self.invitable_type == 'Organization'
      OrgInvitationNotification.with(invitation: self, organization: self.invitable, sender: self.sender).deliver_later(self.recipient)
    end
end
```

**OrgInvitationNotification**

```
# app/notifications/org_invitation_notification.rb

class OrgInvitationNotification < ApplicationNotification
  # this class inherits other delivery methods from ApplicationNotification: database, action_cable, and one_signal
  deliver_by :email, mailer: "InvitationMailer", method: :org_invitation, if: :immediate_email_notifications?

  # required params
  param :invitation
  param :organization
  param :sender

  # helper methods to make rendering easier.
  
  def format_for_action_cable 
    html = ApplicationController.render(
      partial: 'notifications/toast',
      locals: { header: "You've been invited",
                message: message,
                link_path: invitation_path(params[:invitation])
      }
    )
    params.merge(html: html)
  end

  def format_for_one_signal
    {
      message: message,
      data: { page: 'invitation', id: params[:invitation].id }
    }
  end

  def immediate_email_notifications?
    recipient.site_profile.invitations_email_notifications == 'immediately'
  end

  def message
    t(".message", sender: params[:sender].full_name, org_name: params[:organization].name)
  end
  
  def url
    invitation_url(params[:invitation])
  end
end
```

**Update**
New code block per @LamPhan's comments:

```
# From config/application.rb

class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.0

    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
    config.active_record.encryption.support_unencrypted_data = true
    config.active_record.legacy_connection_handling = false

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec,
      fixtures: false,
      view_specs: false,
      helper_specs: false,
      routing_specs: false
    end

    config.autoloader = :classic
end
```

Comment: Just in case... Did you also restart the sidekiq instance?

Comment: what Rails version are you running ?

Comment: @DennyMueller, yes, I did restart the sidekiq instance as well. Just to be sure, I restarted the rails server, redis server, sidekiq instance and the livereload instance. Still a no go. :-(

@LamPhan, I am running Rails 7.0.0.alpha. My Gemfile shows `gem 'rails', :github => 'rails/rails', :branch => 'main'`

I am needing to run the 7 alpha due to using a multidatabase application and needing to write associations between the two. 7.0 adds some work around to that issue. 

I have updated my question with that information.

Comment: are you using `zeitwerk` loader or `classic` ? did you add any file/folder under `notifications` folder to `config.autoload_paths` ?

Comment: @LamPhan, I am not sure on either of your questions. It looks like there is `zeitwerk` in my `Gemfile.lock`, but I am unsure if I am using that or `classic`. How can I tell? Also, `config.autoload_paths` is not showing up anywhere in my code. Where would that have been or shoule it be? In the `application_notification.rb` file?

Comment: on `config/application.rb` file, if you see `config.load_defaults 6.0` and also don't see any `autoload_paths` or `eager_load_paths` relate to `notifications` folder, i think your config OK, then your problem is something else, i see your comment above that you already restart rails/sidekiq, perhaps you could also try restart spring server `spring stop`.

Comment: @LamPhan when I run `spring stop` I get this response: `Spring is not running`. Also, I do not see any of that in my `config/application.rb`, though there is this: `config.autoloader = :classic`. I have added my `config/application.rb` file code to my question above.

Comment: @LamPhan, since I am running Rails 7.0.0.alpha, should my `application.rb` file say `config.load_defaults 7.0` or stay at `config.load_defaults 6.0`? I believe we did update that when we moved from Rails 5.2.3. Maybe that is why?

Comment: @CWarrington base on this comment (of the creator of sidekiq): https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4618#issuecomment-652487812, you should not use `classic` mode (although when i tested on my local proj, sidekiq also work with `classic` mode), i think it's better you use new loader mode `config.load_defaults 6.0` and remove `config.autoloader = :classic`. But i am not sure it'll be ok, maybe your problem is something else, you could try that at first and let see what happen.

Comment: @LamPhan, thank you so much for your help. I figured out the fix! So, when I removed the `config.autoloader = :classic`, all ActiveJobs stopped. But, when I changed it to: `config.autoloader = :zeitwerk`, they all started to work again and no more errors. So, I was able to move the sending of invites to the ActiveJob! Thank you so much for your ideas and helping me solve this issue. If you wish to create an answer, I will mark it as such!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comments, you're using `:classic` loader and your project're running on Rails 7.0.

Base on [this comment (of the creator of sidekiq)](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4618#issuecomment-652487812): `Sidekiq does not work with the classic autoloader in Rails 6 at all.`

so you should use `:zeitwerk` loader.

Comment: Thank you, @LamPhan! This solves the issue that I was having. Thank you so much for your assistance.